# What does "wasApplied()" actually mean for updates to ReactiveCassandraTemplate really mean?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data

```
Mono<WriteResult> result = reactiveCassandraTemplate.delete(...)
```

We are handling `onSuccess()` and `onError()`, but does something need to be handled specially where the `WriteResult` "wasApplied" is false but no error is returned?  What does that actually mean if it didn't fail, BUT it was not applied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`wasApplied` need to be checked](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.6/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html#wasApplied--) if your query contained the conditional update (for so-called [light-weight transactions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html) and for conditional creation of keyspaces/tables, etc.).  So, if this field is equal to `false` then your query was executed but wasn't applied because condition in query didn't allow it.

By default this method always returns true for non-conditional queries.

Comment: Thanks!!!  Makes sense based on what we were kinda thinking but hadn't found details as of yet.